# Orthogonal trajectories problem results in multiple answers.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I was trying to solve the following problem:

**Use polar coordinates to find the orthogonal trajectories of the family of parabolas
$$r=\frac{c}{1-\cos\theta}$$
, $c > 0$. Sketch both families of curves.**

but there is something wrong with my solution and I can't find the mistake.

My Solution:

1. Differentiate $r = \cfrac c{1 − \cos θ}:$

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta} = -\frac{c\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^{2}}$$

2. Replace $c$ with $r(1-\cos θ):$
   $$\frac{dr}{d\theta} = -\frac{r(1-\cos θ)\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^{2}}$$
3. Reduce the fraction and divide by $r$:
   $$\frac{dr}{rd\theta} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)}$$
4. Replace $dr/rdθ$ by its negative reciprocal:
   $$-\frac{rd\theta}{dr} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)}$$
5. Multiply by $-1$, multiply by $dr$, divide by $r$, multiply by $(1-\cosθ)$, divide by $\sinθ$ and integrate:
   $$\int\frac{(1-\cos\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta = \int\frac{dr}{r}$$
6. Result of integration:

$$-\ln|\cos\theta + 1| + C = \ln|r| + C$$

7. Combine the constants and solve for r:
   $$-\frac{(\cos\theta + 1)}{e^{C}} = r$$

Solution in my book is slightly(or not slightly) different:
$$r=\frac{c}{1+\cos\theta}$$

Exercise is taken from the book *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes* by Simmons, section 3 exercise 4

Edit1:
Fixed one mistake in step 7, when removing the natural log the rhs was
$$e^{ln|r|} + e^{c}$$ and not $$e^{ln|r| + c}$$.

Edit2:
Does it matter whether I combine the Integration Constants on the right side or on the left side?(Found it out, it does not).

Thanks for the edits and answers.

Comment: Define "orthogonal trajectories."

Comment: Look at your step #7 again.